# Inserting into another table with a percentile with function

Tags: sql-server

I am calculating percentile with a with function as I am trying to figure out how to get the output to be inserted into another table. So far I got:

```
    WITH PERCENTILES AS (SELECT TMC_code, EPOCH, percentile_CONT(.95)  
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY cast(travel_time_minutes as float)) OVER (PARTITION BY TMC_code) AS P95 FROM [dbo].[AR_2018_TRUCKS_1_3]
WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, EPOCH) between 16 and 17  AND (WKDAY != 'SAT' and WKDAY != 'SUN'))-- and datepart(month, date) = 12)  

insert testtmc
(TMC_code
,P95 
)
select TMC_code
    , P95
from percentiles 
GROUP BY TMC_code
    , P95 
ORDER BY TMC_CODE
```

Answer (score 1):

Your insert statement is all wacky here. You can use a query as the source for an insert statement like this.

```
insert testtmc
(
    TMC_code
    , P95 
)
select TMC_code
    , P95
from percentiles 
GROUP BY TMC_code
    , P95 
ORDER BY TMC_CODE
```

Comment: I'm getting invalid column name with the inserted columns.

Comment: Please update the original post with your table structures (or at least the 2 columns involved)...

Comment: Done and still cannot figure out the incorrect syntax problem.

Comment: There is no syntax issue here. Invalid column is not a syntax error. It means that the columns listed in the insert statement are not in your table. I have no idea what columns in your testtmc table. I just used the names TMC_code and P95 since that is the name from your query. If your column names are different you would need to change them.

Comment: That would be the problem. The testtmc table does not have these columns in it. So I should be using update to insert entirely new columns into the table?

Comment: You can't use an insert to create columns. If you want to insert into a table YOU have to know what columns you want to insert into. I can't see your screen and you haven't provided any real details. I have to say I am a bit nervous that you are using some somewhat complicated sql here but you don't know how an insert statement works. That leads me to believe you don't really understand the query you wrote.

Comment: I use sql server primarily to select data from huge tables that excel and access cannot handle. I don't have much experience with manipulating tables like this. I want to with testtmc to create entirely new columns each time I run my percentiles script with different parameters.

Comment: That sounds like a VERY bad idea. A table should have columns to hold the values it contains. If you have to add new columns all the time it is an indication the table needs to be normalized. To add columns to a table requires the ALTER TABLE statement. This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: I only need four percentile computed values in this table.

Comment: Then you don't want to add a new column every time you run this as you stated. Just change the insert statement above so it inserts into the columns you want to insert to. If there is something else you need to provide the table definition and a clear explanation of what the problem is.

Comment: I am just wondering at this point if there is a way to create the columns and update them with the percentile data within the same code block. That way I don't have to create the columns manually beforehand.

Comment: No. An alter table statement is a completely different animal than an update statement. But you said you only need 4 columns. Why not just create the columns and move forward. This is like asking if you can increase the volume of your gas tank while you are filling it at the pump.